# Kerberos and LDAP?

Tags: ldap, kerberos

I would like to know if LDAP can use Kerberos as a database type?  I have a system that used LDAP and my SA is saying with can use Kerberos as a LDAP database type and I would not have to make any programming changes but the system is safer!

Answer (score 5):

You can use LDAP with Kerberos. A best example for the same is Active Directory. AD is a collaborative tools including of LDAP, Kerberos, DNS & NTP.

You can configure LDAP to save LDAP User Information & Use Kerberos for User Authorization for Single Sign On. You can probably use 389-ds as LDAP and integrate Kerberos with it. 
You can check this for the same http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/linuxvadapav/message/4148 This dont include kerberos part, but you will be able to get LDAP thing working.

For a collaborative suite, you can go for freeIPA http://freeipa.org/page/Main_Page

Answer (score 3):

LDAP has NOTHING to do with a database. LDAP is a protocol only.

A protocol is a defined as:
".. a system of digital message formats and rules for exchanging those messages in or between computing systems and in telecommunications." [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_%28computing%29)

"The Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP;  /ˈɛldæp/) is an application protocol for accessing and maintaining distributed directory information services over an Internet Protocol (IP) network.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_%28computing%29) LDAP is defined in terms of ASN.1 and transmitted using BER."
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol

Comment: You are right but to use ldap we need to configure a backend database for ldap. For example OpenLDAP uses berkley DB (BDB) as default database. Kerberos implements a secure authentication service in which instead of password tickets and session keys are used for authentication in client and server/service. Kerberos can use LDAP database(the database integrated with ldap) to store information, in this way both authentication and authorization can be achieved

Answer (score -1):

You can secure access to existing LDAP database with Kerberos authentication. Most of LDAP server implementations support authentication through SASL API. SASL is a generic abstraction for authentication and supports different methods. One of these methods is GSSAPI which allows wrapping Kerberos authentication. This is, for example, done in Active Directory and FreeIPA, which both allow Kerberos authentication and also store Kerberos credentials within user entries in LDAP.

OpenLDAP has a chapter dedicated on configuring SASL-based authentication:  http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/sasl.html

389-ds, which is another popular open source LDAP server, also has support for SASL authentication. You can read in detail how to secure access to it here: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/9.0/html/Administration_Guide/SecureConnections.html

OpenLDAP and 389-ds examples above assume there is already Kerberos infrastructure deployed in your organisation. If you need to deploy one, I'd recommend to look at FreeIPA, which currently is available in Fedora and RHEL derivatives.